# create dictionary, keys assigned from a list, values extracted from block of text

Tags: python-3.x

I've cobbled this code together over the last week- I've learned a lot but a lot of these concepts are still hard for me to wrap my head around.  I would appreciate any and all help even if its just pointing to the right direction to look.   Thanks in advance for reading...

I get an email with abuse information that needs to be sent out every day.  The pertinent information for each abuse report is dilineated by a line of dashes:

"----------------------------------------------------------------------"

C9/Attacker IP: 9.48.9[.]969

C9 Domain:

Abuse Address: abuse@9.com |

Notice: FIRST

C9 Port(s): 93 |

C9 Active on Our System: 9 Day

Malware Family: gafgyt

Attacks in Last 94 Hours: 9

Attack Samples:

```
Attack Time: 9098-06-99T99:99:00.000Z

    - Victim: 9.59.998[.]999

    - Attack Type: udp

    - Attack Duration: 300 seconds

    - Attack Port: 8080
```

"----------------------------------------------------------------------"

C9/Attacker IP: 9.9.69[.]39

C9 Domain:

Abuse Address: abuse@9.it |

Notice: FIRST

C9 Port(s): 666 |

C9 Active on Our System: 9 Day

Malware Family: mirai

Attacks in Last 94 Hours: 9

Attack Samples:

```
Attack Time: 9098-06-99T99:99:08.000Z

    - Victim: 9.9.948[.]98

    - Attack Type: udp_plain

    - Attack Duration: 300 seconds

    - Attack Port: None
```

"----------------------------------------------------------------------"

There can be any number of abuse reports that need to be sent, there is not a fixed number.

Plan:
1. note line number of dashes:
2. copy lines between dashes into list
3. create dictionary, key ->index of dash lines, value -> list of lines between the dashes

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict
#dashes separate each abuse report in file test2.txt
dashes = "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
#create empty list dash_lines of line #s having dashes
dash_lines = []
#index of which "dash line" to start copying data
index = 0
#index2 tells where to stop (in this case, the next line of dashes found in the document)
index2 = 1
#holds the c2 abuse info, ideally i would want multiple buckets for each abuse report / email to be sent or to have an abuse email sent and corresponding bucket emptied before adding to it again
c2_list = []
#c2_bucket = {}
c2_bucket = defaultdict(list)
```

1. Note Line Number of dashes:

This creates a list of line numbers containing dashes from test2.txt

```
def find_dash_lines():                                                                      
    with open ("test2.txt", 'rt') as c2_email_body:                 #opens (then closes whend done) test2.txt containing abuse info
        for num, line in enumerate(c2_email_body):                  #line count in test2.txt
            if dashes in line:                                      #if dashes are found:
                dash_lines.append(num)                              #append line number to dash_lines list
#               print("Found A dash at line:", num)                 #error testing
        if not dash_lines:                                          #if there's not dash lines in list give error
            print("Could not determine dash line locations")        #to let me know there's an error
        else:
            dash_lines.append(1000)                                 #append line #1000 to end of list to ensure data is captured since there is no trailing dash line for last abuse report
            for num in dash_lines:
                print("Found A dash at line:", num)                 #just to ensure something is happening will eventually comment out
find_dash_lines()
```

2. Extract abuse report between dashes.
   This snip of code is able to extract or print the first abuse report between dashes in test.txt

   def c2_list_function():
       with open ("test2.txt", 'rt') as c2_email_body:                                                                 #opens (then closes whend done) test2.txt containing abuse info
           index = 0
           index2 = 1
           for line in islice(c2_email_body, dash_lines[index], dash_lines[index2]):                                   #looks at line #s in the document from dash_lines[0] to dash_lines[1]- from the first line of dashes found to the next
               line = line.replace("]","")                                                                             #cleanup
               line = line.replace("[","")
               line = line.replace("|",";")
               c2_list.append(line)
               index += 1                                                                                              #increases each index (used to determine where to slice)
               index2 += 1                                                                                             #increases each index (used to determine where to slice)
3. create a dictionary. 
   key should be line number / index from dash_lines
   val should be list of lines from c2_list, each block of text between dash lines

   def c2_dict_function():
       for x in range(len(dash_lines)):
           c2_list_function()
           for line in c2_list:
               print(line, end="")
           c2_bucket[x].append(c2_list)
           c2_list.clear()

The dictionary populates the keys but the values are empty. example output:

```
dict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
dict_values([[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]]])
```

the c2_list also does not seem to populate correctly it looks like it only grabs the first group of info between dashes - i'm assuming i'm not doing the index progression correctly.

Comment: sorry i'm not sure why the code at 2. and 3. is not correctly formatting

Comment: What you posted does not look like an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is unlikely that someone will bother to decipher your post to answer it.